# CSS Animation endless horizontal scroller - pause on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css

I have found this smooth running scroller:

https://codepen.io/wschern/pen/grXwra

Is it possible to pause it on mouse-over?
I have tried animation-play-state: paused; on several elements but it dont work.

```
.animation>div:hover{
  background: red;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this css

```
.animation:hover>div{
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused !important;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused !important;
     animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i think you are looking for this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sL = 4000;
    $('.scrolls').animate({
        scrollLeft : sL
    },100000, 'linear');

    $(".scrolls").on("mouseenter",function(){
        $(this).stop(true,false);
    });
    
    $(".scrolls").on("mouseleave",function(){
        $(this).animate({
        scrollLeft : sL
        },100000, 'linear');
    });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrolls" style="background-color: red; height: 100px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 5000px"> Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..Hello..
    </div>
</div>
```